# Intellij add jar as source

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have a project that uses some jar files that I also develop.
I'm using maven as a build tool, so when I want to make changes in jar, I have to install it first and restart a project.
Is there a way to import this jar into my main project, so that I can make changes right from it and I could use hot swap to apply them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have sources for the other project (which I understand uses maven), you can accomplish this by adding the external project as a module to your active project.

1. Open your active project in IntelliJ.
2. Click `File -> New -> Module from Existing Sources`.
3. Point to the source directory of the other project where the `pom.xml` is located.
4. Hit OK.

You should now be able to modify the source of the jar library directly in your project without needing to publish/install it externally via maven and restart.